# Bash Sudo Command Not Found

Tags: bash, sudo

I have set up a VM using turnkey linux redmine and I'm trying to SSH into the server to install some more items.

It doesn't appear to be recognizing the sudo command. Every time I try to sudo something I get an error saying:

```
 -bash: sudo: command not found
```

I read somewhere else to type 'whereis sudo' and the output was:

```
 sudo:
```

Comment: Ubuntu run: `apt install sudo` as a root user

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks from http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine like Redmine, unlike Ubuntu, does not use sudo by default. What username are you using to SSH in? If it's `root`, then you don't need to use `sudo`, as everything you do when SSHed in to the Redmine system is done as `root`. If it's something else, like `admin`, then you could try using the `su` command to get a `root` shell in which to run commands as `root`.

Comment: What to do when script has commands sudo. Happens to me with mkusb. Its better to install sudo for future convenience .

Comment: **Googlers/Learners**: while the above will work, [Debian wiki says sometimes `sudo` is a better option](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo)

Answer (score 43):

Maybe it isn't installed? Open your package manager and install the **sudo** package.

Comment: It wasn't installed! Thanks. I'm pretty new to Linux and just assumed it was on all installations. Do i just need the sudo package or sudo-ldap as well?

Comment: You don't need the sudo-ldap package. Sudo works fine on my computer and I don't have sudo-ldap installed.

Answer (score 11):

First login to your root account. Then

```
$ apt-get install sudo
```

Add your existing user to group `sudo`

```
$ sudo adduser <user> sudo
```

You should then login as `<user>`, and  the `sudo` command should be there.

Answer (score 5):

try to use full path

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

if that command work then include /usr/bin/ in your env variable PATH in ~/.bashrc

```
echo "export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

hopefully works ..

Comment: That's very unlikely to be the problem; `/usr/bin` is almost certainly going to be in your default path.  The problem, as indicated by other answers and comments, is that the `sudo` command wasn't installed at all.

Answer (score 4):

The error happens because the binary you are trying to call from command line is only part of the current user's PATH variable, but not a part of  root user's PATH.

You can verify this by locating the path of the binary you are trying to access. In my case I was trying to call "bettercap-ng". So I ran,

`$ which bettercap-ng`

`output: /home/user/work/bin/bettercap`

I checked whether this location is part of my root user's PATH.

`$ sudo env | grep ^PATH`

output: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

So sudo cannot find the binary that I am trying to call from commandline. Hence returns the error command not found.

You can direct sudo to use the current user's PATH when calling a binary like below.

`$ sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" [command] [arguments]`

In fact, one can make an alias out of it:

`$ alias mysudo='sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'`

It's also possible to name the alias itself sudo, replacing the original sudo.

Please refer to [this video](https://youtu.be/nTLuTZqQbNI) for step by step solution

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**
When Linux is installed onto your system, the sudo command is installed by default as well. Sometimes, due to some issues, the sudo tool might not exist on your system or may get removed.

**Solution**
Installing the command onto your system is the most suitable method to resolve the error. Firstly to do this you need to enter root user mode. Run this statement in the terminal to enter into root user mode:

```
$ su -
```

Now update your repository:
Once the repository is updated, use the following command to install the sudo command on the system:

```
# apt install sudo
```

Reference: https://itslinuxfoss.com/sudo-command-not-found/

Thank you

Comment: This does not seem to add anything not already mentioned in other answers.  Also, if you are trying to give a generic answer to why `sudo` does not exist rather than addressing the actual question of why it does not exist in a Turnkey Linux Redmine virtual machine, be aware that some distributions have started to use `doas` as a minimal replacement for `sudo` (e.g., Alpine Linux).